# PHP XML fgets и длинные строки

Tags: php, xml, парсер

Задача:
Получить ответ от сервера после POST запроса XML.

Запрашиваем следующим образом:

```
$_SESSION['echo'] = '';
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$sock = fsockopen($host, $port);
fputs($sock, $post);

echo "<pre>";
while (!feof($sock)) {
    $echo = htmlspecialchars(fgets($sock));
    echo $echo;
    $_SESSION['echo'] .= $echo;
}

echo "</pre>";

fclose($sock);
```

Пока все хорошо, данные получаем.
Но размер данных - не известен (если быть совсем точным он зависит от того что мы отправляем на сервер, и может быть как 1-2 кб, так и доходить до мб).

При получении длинного потока данных строки бьются:

```
хидеры

7cb8
строка раз
bff8
строка два
5ffd0
строка три
10a7b
строка четыре
```

и дальше в том же духе.

**Вопрос вот в чем:**
Как избавиться от этих шестнадцатеричных значений, которые вклиниваются между строк?
Можно ли получить очень длинную строку, без её разбития на несколько строк?

P.s. Да, cUrl-ом было бы удобнее, только сервер выдающий информацию не позволяет. Получаем XML в виде одной строки, длинной и страшной. Иногда еще информация ответа немного теряется, но есть подозрение что это некоторые проблемы интернета.

Answer (score 0):

А почему не так?

```
$sock = fsockopen($host, $port);
fputs($sock, $post);

$content = "";
while (!feof($sock)) {
    $content .= fgets($sock);
}

echo htmlspecialchars($content);
fclose($sock);
```

Comment: В целом в Вашей мысли есть правильное решение, но при перемене мест переменных - все еще та же ошибка возникает. При длинной получаемой строке (в том случае если она разбивается на несколько строк) после строки добавляются 16-ричные значения (есть у меня подозрение что пишет кол-во полученных символов \ байт \ еще чего-нибудь).